# Striptag only partial stripping

Tags: twig

Got a particular case of striptags not stripping all tags.

```
{% if field_video|render|striptags %}
<li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#product-vid">{{ field_video['#title'] }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

The above works in removing the "title" according to field value, but leaves the margins and background color. If I use |trim it removes everything, however if a field has "title" value it also strips it.

Additional things I have tried:
|trim is not empty

What else should I look at?

Comment: why don't you use `{% if field_video['#title']|default|trim %}`?

Comment: @DarkBee thank you so much that did it. All the Twig resources I looked at never run across that one. Any resource recommendations I could look at?